# What is part music?

Tags: word-meaning

I was reading John Dewey's Art as Experience. I saw "part-music" phrase. Can anyone explain it to me, please? This is the paragraph:

"What is even more important, the history of music shows that in fact the primitive rhythms, like those of the African negro, are more subtly varied, less uniform, than those of the music of civilized folk, just as those of northern negroes in the United States are usually more conventionalized than those of the south. The exigencies of **part-music** and the potentialities of harmony have operated to reduce to greater uniformity that phase of rhythm that consists in direct variations of intensity, while the theory in question demands a reverse movement."

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on music, but here is what you're looking for:

> Definition of *part music*:
>
> 1: vocal music for several voices in
> independent parts usually without accompaniment
>
> 2: concerted or harmonized music especially of the vocal type

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/part%20music)]

Here is Wikipedia on this topic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_(music)